# Magnitude and phase response still possible to use Matlab's bode function?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, frequency

I have the magnitude and phase response of a system. Now I can plot the bode easily using `semilogx(frequency,abs(response))` (magnitude) and `semilogx(frequency,angle(response))` (phase). However I was wondering if it is possible to use Matlab's `bode` function. Such as `bode(frequency,response)`

The reason I like Matlab's `bode` function is not mainly because it can calculate the magnitude and phase response but also because it provides 2 nice plotting functions which I really like.

1. You are able to select to only the response of a single input-output.
2. You are able to select to only show for example the magnitude or phase response.

So does someone know if this is possible? I guess somewhere there is a function which handles the plotting capabilities of the `bode` function.

---

I figured out that I can create a n x m bode plot using `h = resppack.bodeplot([n,m]);` and I can plot the MIMO response using `h.plot(freq',abs(resp)',angle(resp)');`

But I do not yet have the abilities to select a response or choose to only show magnitude or phase response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `frd` to create a frequency response data model from a frequency response. For that, you will have to create a frequency response with `freqz` from your data. Then you should be able to use `bode(frd)`, as you would usually.

Comment: That indeed sounds nice. But when I have a MIMO system then my frd which consists out of n x m array of frequency responses, they are all plotted in the same figure. And not in seperate subplots. You know if it is still able to do this? Changing the options, http://nl.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/bodeoptions.html, does not seem to work.

Comment: Forget my comment, it works. You only have to specify each a model for each frequency response. H was my nxm frequency response model. Then instead of specifying `sys = frd(H,2*pi*f)`. You should do `sys(1,1) = frd(H(1,:),2*pi*f)`, `sys(2,1) = frd(H(2,:),2*pi*f)`, etc... and then do `bode(sys)`.